# Compute $\int_C \sin x\;dx \; + \cos y\;dy$ along the top half of the unit circle, from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $\int_C \sin x\;dx \; + \cos y\;dy$ along the top half of the unit circle, from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$.

The answer is $0$ but I keep getting $\pi$.  What am I doing wrong here?

$$r(t)=(1-t)r_0+tr_1$$

$$(1-t)\langle 1,0 \rangle+t \langle -1,0 \rangle$$

$$\langle 1-t, 0 \rangle + \langle -t,0 \rangle$$

$x=1-2t$ and $y=0$

So this gives me the following integral:

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \sin(1-2t)+\cos(0)\sqrt{2^2+0^2}$$

When evaluated I get $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization appears to be incorrect. You have used the parametrization of the straight line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$; you are meant to integrate over the upper-half of the unit circle.

The correct parametrization would be $$\vec{r}(t) = (\cos{t},\sin{t})\quad(0\leq t \leq \pi).$$ Now we compute the integral:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{C}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\cos{y}\,\mathrm{d}y & = & 
\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sin{x}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\cos{y}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t})\,\mathrm{d}t\\
& = & \int_{0}^{\pi}(\sin{\cos{t}}\sin{t}-\cos{\sin{t}}\cos{t})\,\mathrm{d}t\\
& = &\left[\sin{\sin{t}}-\cos{\cos{t}}\right]_{0}^{\pi}\\
& = & 0-\cos{1}-0+\cos{1}\\
& = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I know this may sound like a silly question, but how did you come up with that parameterization? I understand why it makes sense, but I just don't know how you got it mathematically.

Comment: This parametrization of the circle is really standard knowledge. Hopefully [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#/media/File:Unit_circle.svg) picture from Wikipedia will help you understand. Geometry is often the most useful tool in coming up with concrete parametrizations (which is often not possible anyway in practice). In this case, the geometry of the situation suggests that the most natural way to parametrize the circle is via the angle at the centre.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I don't think it's the circle I misunderstand, but more the "parametrization" term.  Every since I started this calculus 3 class that term  has confused me :-(.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Coming up with a parametrization is, in general, not easy. For this reason, exercises will often rely on you knowing certain standard parametrizations, like the circle. Have you met polar coordinates yet?

Comment: I have met polar coordinates. Clearly I have not made the relationship between the two.

Comment: If you look at the situation in polar coordinates then it is hopefully clear that the circle in this question (which previously we were using two variables to describe: $x$ and $y$) can be expressed using only one coordinate: set $r=1$ and let $\theta$ vary from $0$ to $\pi$. The only difference is that, in the answer, I have used the letter $t$ rather than $\theta$. This is an important point: *finding the correct coordinate system is (usually) half of the battle*. We need a coordinate system which *allows* us to compute a line integral, i.e., which describes the curve with one variable.

Comment: Of course, you also need to make sure your parametrization is a parametrization for the correct curve: this is harder in general, but, again, looking at things geometrically very often helps.

Comment: Thanks, Will.  Your insights have been extremely helpful!